# Possible real life reasons of adding a custom list object in the same class as a field in java?

Tags: java, list, oop, arraylist, field

I hope the question is not too vague or broad to answer.
I can create the list itself wherever I need it; if I need it as a static field I can make it that too in another classes.
Why would I add a custom list as a field in the very same class?
What are the strengths and weaknesses of this approach in OOP?
Can you explain the differences of the outcomes of these approaches?

Edit: I generally use custom lists as suggested to store multiple instances of a class. I examine other people's code, and I see these approaches where the classes have no parent-child relations with others, yet it's defined as a list object in the same class as a field for to store multiple instances of the class itself. It reminds me infinity mirror effect. So, I wanted to know what I'm missing here.

```
class Record {
        String name;
        String surname;
        String phoneNumber;
        ArrayList<Record> phoneBook; 
    }

class Main {
    String x;
    String y;
    ArrayList<Record> phoneBook; 

}
```

Comment: A class named `Record` containing a `phoneBook` doesn't sound correct, so the design is off. A recursive structure like that is possible and useful in some cases, but not here.

Comment: The approach by itself is ok and may be used to represent any tree-like/hierarchical data structure (`Node` referencing a list of `Node`s, genealogic tree - `Person` having parents and lists of siblings and children, `Employee` having a boss and list of subordinates. etc. )

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you say, suppose you have 10 instances of the Record class and assuming that in each class you stored a list of all those 10 instances then you would actually have 100 and depending on what you do, the performance of your application may be affected.

On the other hand, let's say you have the 10 instances of the Record class but you only store the instance itself in the list, it doesn't make sense, it won't be useful at all.

Finally, the logical thing would be that when creating a list it is to store several instances of the class and then you can access the data of each one, therefore the use of a list in the class itself is not useful in this case.